# Do you have to wash frozen vegetables?

Tags: vegetables, frozen

Do frozen vegetables have pesticides on them? Are you supposed to wash frozen vegetables before you cook them and eat them?

Comment: If concerned about pesticides, there are also organic frozen vegetables on the market these days.

Comment: @NateEldredge Organic still uses pesticides. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_farming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you freeze them yourself and don't wash them first, no, you should not need to wash commercially processed frozen vegetables. Part of the process for freezing includes cleaning/trimming preparing the vegetables. Washing is unnecessary.

Info [here](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-5/Frozen-Vegetable.html):

> The actual process of freezing a food item varies somewhat depending on what is to be frozen. Peas are the most common frozen vegetable, having virtually replaced fresh peas in the American supermarket. The pea process is typical for many vegetables. A typical process for a frozen entrée follows.
>
> Picking and washing
>
> - 2 The peas may be picked by hand or automatically. Then, a machine called a viner removes them from their shells. If the processing plant is adjacent to the fields, the peas are carted there. If truck transport is necessary, they are cooled with ice water and then packed in ice for transport. At the plant, the peas are dumped into beds and sprayed with water to remove dust and dirt.

Answer (score -1):

Frozen produce is not washed. It has dirt, filth from pickers, potentially mold, and pesticides covering it. It is NOT washed on the farm. I work on a farm freezing veggies and berries. We do NOT wash them. Furthermore, as far as berries are concerned, the worst of the bunch gets frozen, while the best berries are packed fresh.

Comment: You said, "We do NOT wash them." Indicating you somehow, have firsthand knowledge of this process. Can you cite it? Or provide more details. I didn't downvote but I can see why someone did.

Comment: I've also worked on a farm for berries - Raspberries and blackberries do not store well washed, so fresh and frozen ones were not washed. Strawberries were not washed fresh, but were for frozen. As to sprays etc, there were stand-down times mandated by law for each spray type before picking could happen. I can't speak for vegetables, but most of the frozen ones I come across clearly have been washed, as most of the fresh ones are too - otherwise carrots etc would be covered in dirt...

Comment: Can you show us a video, maybe on YouTube or D.tube showing the packaging process?